# End of file and while-loop

Tags: c++, file, while-loop, eof

I have a c++ code snippet that is supposed to read some information from a file, and failing to find the file or the information, read it from screen. Here's the code:

```
char c;
bool found=false;
int N;
double step;
ifstream in;
in.open(name.c_str());
if(in) {
    while(!found && in >> c) {
        while(c!='=') in >> c;
        in >> N;
        if(N==wp.N) {
            found=true;
            while(c!=':') in >> c;
            in >> step;
        }
        c='a';
    }
}
if(!found) {
    cout << "max=";
    cin >> step;
}
```

The above is constructed according to the structure of the data in the file, and everything works when the information is in the file (i.e. *N=wp.N* at some point) or the file doesn't exist (i.e. *if(in)* is not true).

But the problem arises when the file exist but doesn't contain the info, that is *N==wp.N* is never true. Then the program freezes (presumably at the end of the file, so that *found* is never true). I was expecting that including *in >> c* inside the *while*-loop would fix this, but I've also tried using *in.eof()*.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find eof() after any of your in >>.

So I'd assume you're looping on while(c!=':') or while(c!='=')

Comment: Thanks both of you! I wish I could put right answer on both the answer, anyway I go with the quickest. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your second loop, which will loop infinitely
if you reach end of file without reading a `'='`.  You need the
`in >> c` in the condition there as well.